# How to find available operations in GraphQL URL?

Tags: python, graphql

Pardon for such vague question. I have a URL `http://example.com/graphql`. I want to know what operations are available. Is there anyway to find it out?

Answer (score 3):

GraphQL has the [introspection system](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Schema-Introspection) which allow you to query its schema.You can construct GraphQL query to explore its types.

For example ,to find out all the query and mutation root fields , you can `POST` the following JSON body to `http://example.com/graphql` with content type set to `application/json`

```
{
   "query" : "{__schema {queryType {name fields {name}}mutationType {name fields {name}}}}"
}
```

Or using `GET` and putting the GraphQL query to the query parameter `query`  :

```
http://example.com/graphql/?query={__schema {queryType {name fields {name}}mutationType {name fields {name}}}}
```

which will return something likes:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "queryType": {
        "name": "Query",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "searchFoo"
          },
          {
            "name": "searchBar"
          }

        ]
      },
      "mutationType": {
        "name": "Mutation",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "createFoo"
          },
          {
            "name": "updateFoo"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

But the much easier way is to use a GraphQL client such as [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or .....  which most probably will provide you an interactive UI to exploring the GraphQL Schema and has some auto-complete/hint feature for assisting you to construct the GraphQL query.

Comment: The easier way is to use Apollo Server which already has a GraphQL playground integrated. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/graphql-playground.html

Comment: @xwlee I am more looking to explore existing graphQL setup.

Comment: I tried it in _PostMan_ and it returned `POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?`

Comment: @Volatil3 . Don't know what happens on your server .I just try it using Postman on this public GraphQL API `https://graphql.brandfolder.com/graphql` and it works

Comment: @Volatil3 . Actually , we can also send GraphQL query using `GET`. see my update and try using GET with `http://zillow.com/graphql` and you would find that they seems to not allow introspection .....

Comment: @KenChan I tried with Get and found `GET query missing.` error.

Comment: @Volatil3 . Suddenly I figure out , try `https://www.zillow.com/graphql/?query={__schema%20{queryType%20{name%20fields%20{name}}mutationType%20{name%20fields%20{name}}}}` . I tried several time , some time it works , sometime it does not.....

Comment: @KenChan It gives `"GraphQL introspection not allowed` error. It does not help me to know actual but thanks for figuring it out.